# Sql query for getting the price for the second latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have this query:

```
select @cost = @cost +                  
    (select top 1 price from
    (select top 2 price, date  from myTable order by date DESC)
     order by date ASC
)
```

And I get error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this subquery

```
(select top 2 price, date  from myTable order by date DESC)
```

needs an alias, like this

```
(select top 2 price, date  from myTable order by date DESC) sq
```

But I'd write it like this:

```
SELECT @cost = @cost + (
SELECT price FROM (
SELECT price, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) AS rownum
) sq WHERE rownum = 2
)
```